# Javascript console error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mp3

I am wondering what is causing the error in the attached javascript console.[image: console screenshot]

A file (mp3 file  /soundcap/soundR8OE41366206103418.mp3) is present physically on the server, the same file is loaded, but also highlighted red in another loading.  This is preventing the file from being played on the browser.  Any insight please?

============

Here is the code I am running:

First, I showed the filename obtained from the server

```
<%= filename %>
```

Secondly, I want to play the file now, and I am using jquery to play the file on clicking playBt.

```
<input type="button" id="playBt" value="Play Now"  >
<audio id="sound" preload="auto">
    <!--source src="snd/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /-->
    <source src="sound/R8OE41366206103418.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Missing `/` between file name and folder? I mean, in the file system.

Comment: The screenshot is VERY tiny, but it looks like there's a slash after /sound in the code (before R8OE...)

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: So if you only add the url to the mp3 file in the location bar it works? I think it might have something to do with response headers. click on the request and check out the request and response headers.

Comment: Somehow you are loading it twice and the second attempt gets canceled. how are you loading this resource?

Comment: @lawson right click and open image in new window. To bdfios; Maybe some javascript's click action is not is triggering the MP3 to load and goes too fast (too fast clicking)? So it cancels another that was still running.

Comment: I guess the file localhost:87/soundcap/soundR8OE41366206103418.mp3 can be opened?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue of adding "/" because I have tried this but din't work still. It even showed an error doing so.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but can you see if the mp3 successfully downloads if you uncomment the "snd/music.ogg" source tag?  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12679476/44084)